# Disable Key Gesture For TabControl in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, user-controls, keyboard-shortcuts, tabcontrol

I've found myself somewhat stumped on how to deal with the following - For simplicity sake, let's say I have two text boxes inside a user control contained in one tab of a `TabControl` and various other controls in the other tabs, which for this example are inconsequential.  When my users hit the tab key to get from one text box to the next, the `TabControl` actually switches tabs...needless to say this is not behavior that can occur in production.  Is there any way I can trap the tab key gesture to the active user control so that it doesn't bubble up?  I tried the following thus far with no luck:

```
XAML
<TabControl.InputBindings>
     <KeyBinding Gesture="TAB" Command="{Binding CancelTabChangeCommand}"/>
</TabControl.InputBindings>

C#
this.CancelTabChangeCommand = new DelegateCommand<object>(t => { });
```

I normally would intercept the preview key down event and check to see if the gestures are those I'm trying to disable and then mark the handled property in the event arguments, but since my app is MVVM, I've drifted a little outside of my expertise on the matter.  Above I was hoping that setting the key gesture to an empty command would override the normal event, but that's obviously not the case.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigation.tabnavigation.aspx) to a different [KeyboardNavigationMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyboardnavigationmode.aspx) than `Continue` to control the behavior of the Tab key within a specified scope.

For example, the following will keep the tab navigation within a user control:

```
<local:MyUserControl KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Contained" />
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked...mostly.  For whatever reason, when I get to the last control within my user control, it then leaves the control, is there any way to block that entirely, where the user would actually have to click outside the control to release it?

Comment: Nevermind, just figured out that "Cycle" will do exactly that.  Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Aaj I wasn't certain which `KeyboardNavigationMode` would work for you, so glad you figured that out :)